# Public function using a Select Case statement spits out #VALUE! errors

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

Based off of a statement in my book, it is calculating whichever PV=NRT value that I choose as the Select Case letter.

```
Public Function ATHING(SolveFor As String, v1 As Single, v2 As Single, v3 As Single, v4 As Single) As Variant

Dim p As Single
Dim v As Single
Dim n As Single
Dim R As Single
Dim t As Single

Select Case SolveFor

Case "P"
    n = v1
    R = v2
    t = v3
    v = v4
ATHING = n * R * t / v

Case "V"
    n = v1
    R = v2
    t = v3
    p = v4
ATHING = n * R * t / p

Case "N"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    R = v3
    t = v4
ATHING= p * v / (R * t)

Case "R"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    n = v3
    t = v4
ATHING = p * v / (n * t)

Case "T"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    n = v3
    R = v4
ATHING = p * v / (n * R)

Case Else
ATHING = "CAN'T FIND VARIALBE TO SOLVE FOR, DO IT AGAIN"

End Select

End Function
```

If I put a number in the Select Case's place, it returns the Else Case. But if I place a Case's letter inside, it returns #VALUE! error, meaning I somehow have an incorrect input somewhere.

The function is located inside a module, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Is there anything obvious?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution, replacing the letters of Case "" with numbers. Excel dislikes having letters and numbers inside its functions, dunno why. I am using 0-4 to represent PV=NRT as they appear in the equation.

```
Public Function ATHING(SolveFor As String, v1 As Single, v2 As Single, v3 As Single, v4 As Single) As Variant

Dim p As Single
Dim v As Single
Dim n As Single
Dim R As Single
Dim t As Single

Select Case SolveFor

Case "0"
    n = v1
    R = v2
    t = v3
    v = v4
ATHING = n * R * t / v

Case "1"
    n = v1
    R = v2
    t = v3
    p = v4
ATHING = n * R * t / p

Case "2"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    R = v3
    t = v4
ATHING= p * v / (R * t)

Case "3"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    n = v3
    t = v4
ATHING = p * v / (n * t)

Case "4"
    p = v1
    v = v2
    n = v3
    R = v4
ATHING = p * v / (n * R)

Case Else
ATHING = "CAN'T FIND VARIABLE TO SOLVE FOR, DO IT AGAIN"

End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Your original function worked fine. I suspect perhaps you weren't putting the string in quotes in the call to your function?